# How to copy files from swap space?

Tags: data-recovery, swap

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. When I was trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, I chose one of major partitions (60G) which contains lots of important files as a swap space. After completing the system installation, I found I had no access to all my files in that partition. That really makes me frustrated. Can someone tell how to copy or recover my files from that partition. Thank you very much!

Comment: Swap space is not a shared data partition. It is empty unformatted partition used as space when RAM memory is full. Stop using drive, do not boot Ubuntu as the live installer version uses swap and will over write more of your data. Use a Linux repairCD that does not auto mount the swap partition. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery  Parted Magic does not mount swap. http://partedmagic.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a useful tool to try to recover data. It is commandline and a bit tricky to figure out how to use, but can do recovery on repartitioned hard disk space very well. It has saved my butt numerous times.